# Remove index thru EntityFramework CodeFirst Migration

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

We now use EntityFramework CodeFirst Migration.
Our database table and index was created long time ago, before we use EntityFramework CodeFirst Migration. 
Our table is myTable, with a column vchMyColumnA and index ColumnA.
Since we used EntityFramework CodeFirst Migration, we have used EntityFramework CodeFirst Migration to add new columns to myTable.

We need to drop Index ColumnA.

1. Do we need to do it thru EntityFramework CodeFirst Migration, or can we just run a script to drop the index ?
2. If we need to drop the index thru EntityFramework CodeFirst Migration, how can I do it ? In Package Manager Console, I typed add-migration DropColumnAIndex, and open the migration code DropColumnAIndex, and added this code:

   ```
   public partial class DropColumnAIndex : DbMigration
   {

       public override void Up()
       {
           DropIndex("dbo.myTable", new[] { "ColumnA" });
       }

       public override void Down()
       {
           CreateIndex("dbo.myTable", "vchMyColumnA");
       }
   }
   ```

Then I typed update-database.
There is no error, and I can see the migration in the database (select * from __MigrationHistor), but index ColumnA is still there.

Thank you.

Comment: Is "ColumnA" a typo? Your Down() code refers to it as "vchMyColumnA". I like to script these issues out and see what SQL is produced. `update-database -Script`.

Comment: No, unfortunately, the index is called "ColumnA", and the column itself is called "vchMyColumnA". When I do update-database -Script, it returns this script: IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = N'IX_ColumnA' AND object_id = object_id(N'[dbo].[myTable]', N'U'))
    DROP INDEX [IX_COLUMNA] ON [dbo].[myTable]. 
How can I drop index "ColumnA" on column "vchMyColumnA" thru EF CodeFirst Migration ? Can I just run a script to do that ? THank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, hard to write this in a comment. You can inject the equivalent SQL into your migration:

```
public override void Up()
{
    Sql("DROP INDEX ColumnA ON [dbo].[myTable];"); 
}
```

Comment: That works ! Thank you !
What do I put in the Down() code ? Is this code still ok ?
CreateIndex("dbo.myTable", "vchMyColumnA");

Comment: Yes, that will re-add the index.